# Django admin shows randomly 504 Gateway Time-out

Tags: django, nginx, django-admin, gunicorn, supervisord

In the django admin, when openning the change_list view of one of my django models I sometimes (not always) get a "**504 Gateway Time-out**" after about 5 seconds.

When the error appears, there's an "**Ignoring EPIPE**" message in the gunicorn log.

It's an supervisor-gunicorn-nginx-django environment.

In the supervisor configuration I tried

```
timeout=60
```

In the nginx configuration I've got

```
proxy_connect_timeout 60;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
```

If I remove most of the elements of the model, it seems the error disappears but I'm not completely sure about this.

Comment: Can you access the same page but using gunicorn directly? i.e. use the gunicorn port in the URL. If you do that you may be able to determine whether the page is indeed slow and causing nginx to time out, or whether it is caused by some other problem.